# Drupal 7 - Confirm email address

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have added some extra fields to the standard '*create account*' page; notably a '*confirm email*' field.

How do hook into the validation so that I can add some custom validation rules of my own (e.g. to check the two emails match)?

I have found **hook_user_presave**, but am unsure on how to code it or where I should put it.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise installing the [LoginToboggan module](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan), it actually has the option for that exact functionality out of the box and has a bunch of other useful options as well.

If you want to do it yourself though you'd probably be better off implementing [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and adding a validation function directly to the [registration form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_register_form/7):

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_form_validate';
}

function mymodule_user_register_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['first_email'] != $form_state['values']['second_email']) {
    form_set_error('second_email', 'The email addresses much match.');
  }
}
```

Make sure you clear Drupal's cache once you've implemented the form alter function so Drupal registers it correctly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see this answer is accepted, but I think the code snippet is missing a bit of code. Where is the $form['second_email'] field getting created?

Comment: @greggles It was a while ago but I probably just put those field names in as an example; `$form['first_email']` wouldn't be there as standard either

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example solution for Drupal 7:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 * Note: You can define your own menu callback optionally.
 */
function foo_menu() {
  $items['foo-signup'] = array(
    'title' => 'Create new account',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('user_register_form'),
    'access callback' => 'user_register_access',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function foo_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['account']['mail_confirm'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Confirm e-mail address'),
    '#maxlength' => EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => t('Please confirm your e-mail address.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['#validate'][] = 'foo_user_register_form_validate';
}

/**
 * Implements validation callback.
 */
function foo_user_register_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['mail'] != $form_state['values']['mail_confirm']) {
    form_set_error('mail_confirm', 'The email addresses must match.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is working great for my registration page, but the confirmation field is being displayed beneath the password fields... in this order: [email] [password] [password confirm] [email confirm]. How can I re-sort these so that the [email confirm] field is directly after the [email] field?

Comment: @hockey2112 You can try adding `#weight` attribute with some values.

Comment: Adding the weight attribute does affect it, but a weight of "-1" puts the confirmation field above the Email Address and Password fields, and any weight 0 or greater puts it back at the bottom, below those fields. It appears that the Email Address and Password fields all have a weight of "0". Any ideas on how to get around that?

Comment: @hockey2112 You can ask another question then, as I won't be able to get into further details. Sorry about it.